# Why my database disappeared then appeared and now again is disappeared?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I am on cpanel, and working with phpmyadmin.

I create a subdomain, then I create a database, and I changed some of my settings.(2days ago)

But now when I login to cpanel, I see that there is something just like `ctrl + z`! I mean The only database that was created 5 month ago is now remained and the database which I create it 2 days ago is NOT in my databases list! + I changed the menu settings(put the 'databases' menu on the top, put the 'preferences' menu on the bottom of the cpanel home page and ...) but now there are just like the default cpanel setting.

What's the problem?

- I am 75% sure that my cpanel login is NOT hacked.
- I've changed the cpanel password but not the phpmyadmin password.

Comment: there might be some trouble with user-privileges on the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may only be allotted one database with your webhost. Contact their support.

Answer (score 0):

Your host may have restored a backup. Ask them.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar occur with my vps account recently. While my databases show up within the mysql database menu list they're no longer available in the backup menu. I tried changing themes and it corrected the problem. The theme I had the problem with is X3.

In my situation I believe the theme must have been broken due to a recent control panel update as I noticed the login page has changed drastically but I'm not sure if that's the same issue you're dealing with.

To clarify, I changed the theme within WHM not cpanel. From X3 to X2. X2 is apparently depreciated so this isn't a long term fix to whatever the underlying issue is; just thought I'd share in case it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem.

I contact with the host provider, and I found out the problem. He said according to the internet problem in your place and also our previous actions to change the server, your host is sometime, loaded by the new server, and sometime by the previous one! So when I create a database from my computer it connect to the first one, then you browse web or again I check the website from another place, then I connect to the second server, and see that there isn't any database!

I don't have much experience, so I don't know, this answer is true or just for kidding!